# Mozilla extension - save and load with mozilla storage API

Tags: javascript, jquery, storage, mozilla

I am currentrly trying to store user data for a mozilla extension with the [mozilla storage api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage) from an `<textarea>` element and got some trouble loading the data back into a variable.

Here's my functions:

```
//Saving the user settings
function saveSettings()
{
  var tags = $('#tagsList').val();
  browser.storage.local.set({tags});
}

//Loading the user settings
function getStoredTags()
{
  var tags = browser.storage.local.get("tags");
  tags.then(onAccept, onError);
}

//onAccept Event
function onAccept(item)
{  
  console.log(item);
}
```

I have no problems to get the user data back to a variable inside the onAccept event (as a string) like this:

```
function onAccept(item)
{
  var loadedItems = Object.values(item);
}
```

But how can I return them with my getStoredTags() function?

```
function getStoredTags()
{
  var tags = browser.storage.local.get("tags");
  tags.then(onAccept, onError);
  var loadedTags = //get here the user data tags string from the onAccept event
  return loadedTags;
}
```

Am I'm using the wrong way to get back the stored user data?

Comment: you have to sepcify what you set `...local.set('tags',value);`

Comment: I have tried it with the key-value pair but I'm not able to save anything. However in my example above I am able to save my variable into the local storage. But my main question, how to load the stored data back into a variable so I can return it with my function, still remains.